# Powershell - Truncate characters within a string

Tags: powershell

I have to truncate the following lines text. The only text to be truncated to 34 character is the part I have bolded. It is possible the characters (bolded) in the description could be under (in which case just leave the line as is) or over 34 characters.

The line has to be terminated with a ' character.

IMD+F++:::**Be-Light Fruit Yog VLF4x(6x120g)**'

I've got close with some code but then got a bit stuck and now my brain hurts - I imagine somewhere in the world it is early in the day and people have fresh minds!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: 34 from the beginning or the end? What you have in bold is 32... Your question isn't making sense to me.

Comment: How do you know what part of the string is subject to truncation? Is the prefix always the same? (e.g. "IMD+F++:::") or is it the string of colons???

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$string1="IMD+F++:::Be-Light Fruit Yog VLF4x(6x120g)'"
$string2 = $string1 -replace '(.*:+)(.*)','$2'
$res = if ($string2.length -gt 34) {$string2.Substring($($string2.length-34))}else{$string2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following examines a string after a sequence of `:::`s and determines if it needs truncated.

```
$str = "IMD+F++:::Be-Light Fruit Yog VLF4x(6x120g)'"
$prefix = $str -replace ":::.*",":::"
$trunc = $str -replace ".*:::",""
if ($trunc.length -gt 34)
{
    $trunc = $trunc.Substring(0,33) + "'"
}
Write-Host "$prefix$trunc"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string -replace "(.*:::)([^']{1,33}).+",$('$1$2' + "'")
```